# How can I pass certain properties to the Spring context through servlet params?

Tags: spring, embedded-jetty

So we decided to deploy our application no more as a war on the usual tomcat, but from an embedded jetty. My app uses `context:property-placeholder` to resolve properties from a file. Now I'd need to pass some (or all) properties programatically before starting jetty. Is there a way that allows me to set some properties by code, before running jetty, instead of relying on the .properties file? For example as Servlet params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. This PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extract the properties from the servlet context init params.

From [Spring Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html):

> Subclass of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer that resolves placeholders as ServletContext init parameters (that is, web.xml context-param entries).

But this class is deprecated from Spring version 3.1.

From version 3.1 you don't need to use any special configuration because all Web Based servlet context use the class [`org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment.html) that resolve properties from servlet context params by default.